# relation between the group $O(3)$ and $SU(2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Base on relations between groups $O(3)$, $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$:

a) $O(3)=SO(3)\otimes \{1,-1\}$

b) $SO(3)\simeq SU(2)/Z_2$

Can I say $\{1,-1\}$, i.e. $Z_2$, also the center of the group $O(3)$? If so, is $O(3)\simeq SU(2)$ (both locally and topologically)?

Can anyone help me with my above confusion? Any hints or reference are welcome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same. $O(3)$ is not connected (they have $det = \pm 1$), while $SU(2) \cong \mathbb S^3$ is connected. However, they are all locally the same, as $O(3)$ is locally the same as $SO(3)$ and $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ is a covering.

Comment: Hi John, thanks a lot for your reply. If $SU(2)\simeq S^3$, what's the topology of O(3)?

Comment: As $SO(3)$ is topologically a $\mathbb{RP}^3$, I suppose $O(3)$ is $\mathbb{RP}^3 \times \mathbb Z_2$.