# Relation between $SU(2)$ and $O(3)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-homomorphism, orthogonal-matrices, unitary-matrices

This is almost identical (even one may say "duplicate" of) to this [relation between the group $O(3)$
and $SU(2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542047/relation-between-the-group-o3-and-su2). But i would like to ask one more question. Does this relations (given at the "link") mean we can find a isomorphism between $SU(2)$ and $O(3)$ but not continuous group isoomorphism (lie group isomorphism).

Continuos group isomorphism doesn't exist it is clear as mentioned in the "link". But both groups "look like" $SO(3)\otimes \{1,-1\}$ so they should be isomorphic??

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: are you familiar with group extensions? $SU(2)$ is a nonsplit extension of $C_2$ by $SO(3)$ while $O(3)$ is a split extention (semidirect product) of $C_2$ by $SO(3)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are no isomorphic. For instance, $SU(2)$ only has an element with order $2$ (which is $-\operatorname{Id}$), where is each matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}\pm1&0&0\\0&\pm1&0\\0&0&\pm1\end{bmatrix}$$other than the identity matrix is an element of $O(3)$ which has order $2$.

Comment: I think you wanted to wrote something like this? $$ \begin{bmatrix} \ 0 & 0 & -1 \ 0 & -1 &0 \ -1 &0 &0 \ end{bmatrix} $$ is element of O(3) and has order 2. because what you wrote was very mind confusing for me but i get the point i believe. Also i'm wondering why then we obtain such a notation because doesn't b) $SO(3)\simeq SU(2)/Z_2$ imply $SO(3)\otimes Z_2 = SO(3)$ and as the user says can't we just identify $Z_2$ with $\{I,-I\}$ i guess answer is no,somehow, but it is confusing.

Comment: I've edited my second sentence.

Comment: I very much like to give a green tick  but i'm little confused. Could you clarify my question or my mind a little bit more? Doesn't b) $SO(3)\simeq SU(2)/Z_2$ imply $SO(3)\otimes Z_2 = SU(2)$ and can't we just identify $Z_2$ with $\{I,-I\}$ ? I'm repeating my other comment but i cannot edit it no more

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb Z_2\simeq\{\operatorname{Id},-\operatorname{Id}\}$, but no, it doesn't follow from the fact that $SO(3,\Bbb R)\simeq SU(2)/\{\operatorname{Id},-\operatorname{Id}\}$ that $SO(3,\Bbb R)\simeq SU(2)\times\{\operatorname{Id},-\operatorname{Id}\}$. That's normal in groups theory. For instance, the group $S_3$ of all permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ has a normal subgroup $A_3$, which is $\{\operatorname{Id},(1\ \ 2\ \ 3),(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)\}$. And $S_3/A_3\simeq\Bbb Z_2$. However, $S_3\not\simeq A_3\times\Bbb Z_2$. For instance $A_3\times\Bbb Z_2$ is abelian, whereas $S_3$ is not.